# How to remove a Bookmark from a document?

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

Because OOXML documents don't seem to follow proper XML rules, a Bookmark consists of a `BookmarkStart`, a `BookmarkEnd` and an arbitrary number of elements in-between; not a hierarchy but a single flow of elements which have to be traversed in the right order:

```
<w:bookmarkStart w:id="4" w:name="Author"/>
    <w:r w:rsidR="009878B3"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:t>&lt;</w:t></w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidR="005E0909"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidR="009878B3"><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="28"/></w:rPr><w:t>Author&gt;</w:t></w:r>
<w:bookmarkEnd w:id="4"/>
```

I already ran into this problem in a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219201/how-to-get-the-text-of-a-bookmark-as-a-single-string

But this question is, how can I remove the Bookmark entirely from the document, without breaking anything? Do I have to iterate through siblings from the `BookmarkStart` until I reach a `BookmarkEnd`? Is there some useful API method which makes up for the failure to use XML properly whereby one would just have a `Bookmark` node which could be deleted?!

Comment: If you have control over the source documents, you might consider using content controls instead of bookmarks.  Content controls are much nicer from an XML point of view.

Comment: @JasonPlutext I've never heard of these. I'd welcome an answer based on this as we do control the documents.

Comment: See generally https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157891.aspx  You'll want a rich text content control.  These can be nested.  Add one using the developer menu in Word.  For the openxml-sdk, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.sdtblock(v=office.14).aspx (note there is a different class depending on whether the content control aka sdt is block level, inline, surrounds a table row, or a table cell)

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the `BookmarkStart` via the API and it will remove the corresponding `BookmarkEnd` for you and leave any contents intact. In `C#` something like this should work:

```
public static void RemoveBookmark(string filename, string bookmarkName)
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filename, true))
    {
        Body body = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

        //find a matching BookmarkStart based on name
        BookmarkStart start = body.Descendants<BookmarkStart>().FirstOrDefault(b => b.Name == bookmarkName);

        if (start == null)
        {
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Bookmark {0} not found", bookmarkName));
        }

        //this is clever enough to remove the BookmarkStart and BookmarkEnd
        start.Remove();

        wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's very useful to know, but it's actually the whole bookmark including the contents I wish to remove, not just to "unbookmark"